# Feature list of Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-list

I am looking for a complete documentation on what all stackoverflow supports or provides in terms of its features?

Comment: No proper doc is available, just a bunch of posts here on meta, look for [sofaq] tags.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a single feature list or design document available to detail all the features of StackOverflow. Most of that information can be found by perusing the various SOFAQ-tagged posts on StackOverflow. This will give you a very detailed run-down of the way things work and the way the community is set up to perform.